# How do I instance a small object evenly along a complicated shape?

Tags: bezier-curves, instances

I made this mathematical mesh and I'd like to add 10 regularly spaced small spheres along each of its curves spiraling out from the center, like the highlighted one. The problem is that the vertices themselves are not evenly spaced (they get farther apart toward the outside).

How can I do this?

At first I thought I could use the instancing tool but I definitely don't want one sphere per vertex.

[image]

Comment: one way you can do is duplicate the selected vertices, separate as new object and the give it a geometry modifier and use poisson disc with the distance you like and very high density.

Comment: @Chris thank you, how do you do that for a set of vertices? I can only get points distribute to work when the points are distributed over a volume mesh. On a line I don't see any generated points.